# React.PropTypes.element don't accept React.DOM.input etc

Tags: reactjs

Concider this:

```
MyComponent = React.createFactory React.createClass
  displayName: 'MyComponent'
  propTypes:
    comp: React.PropTypes.element

  render: ->
    div {},
      this.props.comp {id: 'dummy1'}
```

---

```
AppView = React.createClass
  render: ->
    MyComponent {comp: React.DOM.input}
```

This throws the following error:

```
Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `comp` supplied to `MyComponent`,
expected a ReactElement. Check the render method of `Radium(AppView)`.
```

Am I missunderstanding the docs https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html ? Is `React.DOM.input` not an "element"?

(React version 0.13.3)

Comment: `React.DOM.input` is a DOM element, not a react component.

Comment: This does not answer your question, but maybe it solves your problem: you could try to make `React.DOM.input` a child of `MyComponent`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`React.DOM.input` is not a ReactElement, but a React class.

To simply fix your Warning/Error message, you would have to change

```
propTypes:
    comp: React.PropTypes.element
```

to

```
propTypes:
comp: React.PropTypes.func
```

since `typeof React.DOM.input` is a class, aka. `function`.

To create a `React.PropTypes.element` you would have to call `React.DOM.input`.